# Is the automatic ban policy configurable?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am trying to talk my boss into using a Stack Exchange clone for our Q&A site.  So I do not have a clone yet.  I am trying to collect information to present to him.

One desire of my boss would be the removal of the automatic ban.  Is it possible to turn this off or to change the parameters by which it is enforced?

*Side question:  Does this question belong here or on the API site?*

Comment: Where did you get the clone from? Wouldn't the supplier of the clone be best placed to answer this?

Comment: If you're using a clone, the SE policy on bans doesn't matter.

Comment: @RobertLongson i don't have a clone (yet).  This is a pre-emptive question to see if we want to get a clone.  (I am trying to talk my boss into it, so collect information to present to him.)

Comment: How would we know the functionality of a clone that you've not yet chosen? Clones are functional copies, not code copies. They may or may not have coded this in the same way as Stack Exchange have.

Comment: Updated question to be clearer

Comment: @RobertLongson Sounds like he's asking about having SE provide a site for his company (a service that they do actually offer), and wanting to know if this configuration can be made for such a site.

Comment: If you're specifically talking about the [enterprise option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/226203) they've indicated exists, this is probably something you'd need to ask SE directly when purchasing. Details on how closely it mimics the public code are sparse, to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is configurable by the SE engine.  Most SE sites don't even have a question ban, it's only the larger sites, such as SO, that have it enabled.  It can also be tweaked, rather than simply turned on or off.  For example, this site (meta.stackexchange) has a question ban, but the threshold for reaching it is much higher than on other sites.